# Rails fresh install throws TypeError, points to spring gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I keep getting the following error when I try to use the rails command from within my application directory:

```
/Users/useraccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
```

---

Here's how I got there...

After installing and updating all the necessary software, I am beginning with the following configuration:

- Mac OS Sierra 10.12.5
- xcode 8.3.3
- Rails 5.1.1
- ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-darwin16] <strike>ruby 2.4.0p0 (2016-12-24 revision 57164) [x86_64-darwin16]</strike>
- rubygem 2.6.12
- Homebrew 1.2.3
- Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision ab5ba7; last commit 2017-06-19)

I went into my project folder and ran the following:

```
$ rails new testapp
...output omitted...
$ cd testapp
$ rails s
```

This is the point where I get the TypeError. If I run `rails -v` it gives me the same error.

---

Here's the full trace:

```
/Users/useraccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
    from /Users/useraccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/useraccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/useraccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/useraccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/useraccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    from /Users/useraccount/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/useraccount/Google Drive Family/code/Rails/12-Week-Challenge/Week_0 [Dry Run]/testapp/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    from /Users/useraccount/Google Drive Family/code/Rails/12-Week-Challenge/Week_0 [Dry Run]/testapp/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

---

#### Update 1:

I upgraded ruby from 2.4.0 to 2.4.1 and the exact same problem persists.

```
/Users/brianjason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
```

#### Update 2:

when I comment out spring in the `Gemfile` the application runs without error:

```
group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  #gem 'spring'
  #gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
```

Then I attempted to move forward with developing the application.
I followed the steps outlined in section 4 of the [rails getting started guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

Here's what I got when I tried to run the app:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (bad URI(is not URI?): file:///Users/useraccount/Google%20Drive%20Family/code/Rails/12-Week-Challenge/Week_0%20[Dry%20Run]/testapp/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css?type=text/css&pipeline=debug):
    4:     <title>Testapp</title>
    5:     <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    6:
    7:     <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    8:     <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    9:   </head>
   10:

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___42966888540102183_70217709639480'
```

Comment: How did you install Ruby? Did you use RVM or RBENV?

Comment: RVM. I am using the latest stable version.

Comment: Have you tried `gem uninstall rails` then reinstalling it?

Comment: Also try using a current stable version of Ruby either Ruby 2.3.4 or Ruby 2.4.1. those can be found here https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/

Comment: Yes. I completely uninstalled rails, Ruby and rvm and then reinstalled. There was no change in the error I was receiving.

Comment: I would try a different version of Ruby. You are using 2.4.0p0 and there were some issues with Rails and Ruby 2.4.0.

Comment: Ok I upgraded to ruby 2.4.1 (using rvm) and it continues to give me the same error. See details in original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the problem was the result of the folder names in my working directory's path. It appears as though the spaces in the folder names were causing the error.

Once I removed the spaces and changed the folder names from:

```
/Users/useraccount/Google Drive Family/code/Rails/12-Week-Challenge/Week_0 [Dry Run]/testapp/
```

to:

```
/Users/useraccount/Google_Drive_Family/code/Rails/12-Week-Challenge/Week_0_DryRun/testapp/
```

everything worked perfectly. Problem solved.